# Is there a simple way to optimize code in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I hope to optimize Code A, but Code B failed.

Is there a simple way to optimize the code A in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
mediaPlayer?.let {
   if (it.isPlaying){
      it.stop()
   }
}
```

**Code B**

```
 mediaPlayer?.isPlaying?.stop()
```

Comment: In cad B you're checking if `isPlaying` is not null, not if it's true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Kotlin construct you seem to be looking for is `takeIf`:

```
mediaPlayer?.takeIf{ it.isPlaying }?.stop()
```

`a.takeIf { condition }` returns `a` iff `condition == true`, otherwise it returns `null`.